# Should there be a preference in adding new training samples?

Tags: train-test-split

In a binary example, if you have a training and testing set of samples, should you attempt to add additional samples similar to test set observations with predicted class probabilities near 50%?

Would this promote efficient class labeling to make a better model?

Comment: “should you attempt to add additional samples similar to test set”—You shouldn’t look at the test set distribution at all! It’s the fast road to overestimating how good your model is.

Comment: But if your training set is small (and not encompassing the extent of observation variance), couldn't this indicate a lack of observations in your training set?

Comment: You don’t get to decide this by looking at your test set. That’s the point of a test set. What you propose is called data leakage.

Comment: Couldn't this be thought as imbalanced observations within a class? If a model was trained on 1 observation with certain characteristics (in its features) and the test set had 5 of these similar observations, wouldn't it be good to add more samples of this type of feature space?

Comment: Look up active learning Jason. This is similar to what you are talking about, where you intelligently add new samples by labelling unlabelled data. One of the strategies is to select these data where the predicted class probabilities are near 50% (ie uncertain)

Comment: @astel thank you! I wasn't aware of this! If you'd like to edit my question in a way that would be found by others, please do so. I'll accept this as an answer if you respond below.

Comment: Are you thinking of active learning? Looking at the test set is not such a good idea (unless you are in a Kaggle competition and can do so), but if you have many unlabelled samples, then deciding which ones to label (when that's expensive) is what's called "active learning".

Comment: To be clear: Active learning still mustn’t peek at the test set.